# No sense of direction of what to do next in C++, what to learn next?

Tags: c++

I am studying game dev. I have learnt C++ on my own I would say my skills are about intermediate level but I most of my stuff is done from console games i.e anything text based.

What is the next step I should take? I have looked at some DirectX stuff it does not look to appealing is there any steps anyone could offer?

Comment: The first step you should probably take is reading the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq/).

Comment: I see a trend in your comment history...

Comment: That's not what "console games" means.

Comment: @jhocking +1 funny indeed.

Comment: Why is DirectX not appealing? Too difficult?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're question is GDSE appropriate, but this is all I can offer:

Grab a library/engine. Follow the instruction/tutorials. Start building. A lot of stuff is already done for you ( like sound/graphics/controls ) so you don't have to reinvent the wheel.  [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines) is a list of engines ( check the licenses, some might not be free. I havn't checked them all ).

Answer (score 1):

There are many components in game programming, e.g. rendering, audio, input, data structures, AI, networking etc. DirectX is a package that offers API for several of that, and as such makes it a relatively difficult package for learning.

For me, as a noob in this area, I learnt other programming lanaguages that offer out-of-the-box GUI rendering e.g. VB6, .NET, JAVA, ActionScript. This removes the need for handling the rendering myself.

Then I play some retro games like Pong, Pacman, Tetris, Space Invaders, Paddle Ball etc and try to implement the same thing with the programming langauges to hone me skills in game architecture.

As I try to make my games better, and from 2D to 3D, I eventually hit hard limitations and then I "upgrade" my technology by using more low level APIs. Doing this allowed myself to appreciate the need and reasoning behind each API's implementation.

When you are expert enough, you can forget all the low level stuff and use an engine like Unity3D.